# LOAD DATA FROM S3 The provided token has expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora

I am trying to load data from S3 bucket to a specific table in aurora db. When I run the query from MySQL Server Workbench I get an error:

Error Code: 1871. S3 API returned error: Unknown:Unable to parse ExceptionName: ExpiredToken Message: The provided token has expired.

I have configured the IAM Role to have access on S3 bucket and  also configured the parameter group to set the role arn but the same issue. 
I resigned the role to aurora instance but no success.

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://xxxx/xxx/'
                INTO TABLE xxxxxx
                CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 ROWS
                            (@col1, @col2)
                            SET col1 = nullif(@col1,'\N'),  
                            col2 = nullif(@col2,'\N'))
```

It should return success and the number of rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different parameter group variables that could possibly be set to the IAM role:

- aurora_select_into
- aurora_load_from
- aws_default

I've experienced odd issues with assigning *select* and/or *load* to the IAM role in the past, but if I set **only** the *default* role everything works. (screenshot 1)

Two other things to check:

- Value is set to the full ARN of the role you want to use. (screenshot 1)
- After you update the parameter group, make sure it has been fully applied to the instance. You should see the words "in-sync" when you select your db instance from the web console. If not, your instance may require a reboot. (screenshot 2)

[image: aws rds parameter group s3]

[image]